# Weird behavior when counting messages on JMS queue

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I am using Active MQ and the Java JMS.

I want to count the number of messages on the queue.

One approach is counting the messeages with a browser:

```
    Queue queue = (Queue) session.createQueue(subject);
    QueueBrowser queueBrowser = session.createBrowser(queue);
    Enumeration<?> e = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
    int numMsgs = 0;
    // count number of messages
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    //    Message m = (Message) e.nextElement();
        e.nextElement();
        numMsgs++;
    }
```

But for a queue with 5000 pending requests, this only return 500.

Another approach is this (iterate all the messeages in the queue):

```
Message message= consumer.receive(500);
while(message!= null)
    {

        if (message instanceof TextMessage) 
        {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
       //     BytesMessage Byte

            System.out.println("Received message '"+ textMessage.getText() + "'");
        }
        if(message!=null)
            Messages_list.add(message);

        message = consumer.receive(1);
    }
```

But this also dont give the right amount of messages pending.

How can i confidently iterate akk the messages waiting in the queue?

Comment: Very weird behaviour, I've always had good experience with QueueBrowser. Silly questions but still - are you sure you are looking into right queue? How did you determine that there are 5000 messages? `Imqadmin` that's shipped with Glassfish often doesn't have up-to-date info about nr of messages, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bug in ActiveMQ that is preventing the browse from returning the actual number of messages.  In this case the browse is only returning a single page of messages, which is set by the maxPageSize property and documented here: http://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies.html

ActiveMQ currently has a bug report on this issue and it is being tracked here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4181. This issue has been resolved and is currently scheduled to be fixed in ActiveMQ 5.8.0.

Comment: So I guess this is only the first 200 messages on the queue, you wouldn't be able to retrieve the most recent 200 messages :( ?...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ActiveMQ, you can make use of ActiveMQ's StatisticsPlugin: http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html

> Similarly, to query the statistics for a destination just send a message to the destination name prepended with ActiveMQ.Statistics.Destination. For example, to retrieve the statistics for a queue whose name is TEST.FOO, send an empty message to the queue named ActiveMQ.Statistics.Destination.TEST.FOO

Specifically, you might be interested in `enqueueCount`.
I'm omitting example code here, since the example code on the plugin's webpage are concise and good.